# How do I change the bundler called in Capistrano 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, bundler

I am deploying in a multiuser, multiserver environment (Site5).
I am deploying a rails 4 app.  The default environment is ruby 1.8.7, rails 3.0.
There is access to local versions of ruby, 
Things are working until the bundler is called.
Here's the error snippet:

```
INFO [4439d586] Running /usr/bin/env bundle install --path /home/username/apps/todos/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet as username@dirktaylor.ca
DEBUG [4439d586] Command: cd /home/username/apps/todos/releases/20160121174533 && ( export RUBY_BIN_PATH="/usr/local/ruby20/bin" PATH="/usr/local/ruby20/bin:/usr/username/ruby/gems/gems/bundler-1.11.2/exe:$PATH" ; /usr/bin/env bundle install --path /home/username/apps/todos/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet )
DEBUG [4439d586]        Gem::InstallError: i18n requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
DEBUG [4439d586]        An error occurred while installing i18n (0.7.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install i18n -v '0.7.0'` succeeds before bundling.
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as username@dirktaylor.ca: bundle exit status: 5
bundle stdout: Gem::InstallError: i18n requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
An error occurred while installing i18n (0.7.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install i18n -v '0.7.0'` succeeds before bundling.
bundle stderr: Nothing written
```

As you can see, I am setting  environment variables before the bundle command is called.

So, here's what I've figured...
Because Capistrano 3 is executing everything with `/usr/bin/env` and `/usr/bin/env bundle install ...` in particular, it is not finding the correct version of bundler to use.

```
username@dirktaylor.ca [~2]# /usr/bin/env bundle -v;whereis bundle
Bundler version 1.2.1
bundle: /usr/bin/bundle
```

(Note: /usr/bin/env is linked to /bin/env )

I have installed the current user of bundler (`gem install bundler`) which is now in ~/ruby/gems/gems/bundler-1.11.2 with executable script at ~/ruby/gems/gems/bundler-1.11.2/exe/bundle

So?  Now What?
1) How can I get this version of bundler to execute?
2) Also, inside the script it calls `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`.  Should I change this to the correct ruby path?
3) I saw this solution for Cap 2 elsewhere:

```
set :bundle_cmd, "/usr/username/ruby/gems/gems/bundler-1.11.2/exe/bundle"
set :bundle_dir, "/usr/username/ruby/gems/gems/bundler-1.11.2"
```

So the question remains: How do I change the bundler called in Capistrano 3?

(Finally:  Can this be solved without rvm?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Capistrano 3 there is a concept of a ["command map"](https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit#the-command-map) that lets you override the string used for any arbitrary command. In the case you want to map `bundle` to `/usr/username/ruby/gems/gems/bundler-1.11.2/exe/bundle`, let's say.

You do that like this:

```
# Put this in deploy.rb or production.rb, etc.
SSHKit.config.command_map[:bundle] = "/usr/username/ruby/gems/gems/bundler-1.11.2/exe/bundle"
```